# How to pass list to Cmake function by reference

Tags: list, cmake, pass-by-reference

I want to pass a list to a function in Cmake, edit the list, and use the new value in the calling function.

I have tried this code:

```
function(foo my_list)
  message(
    STATUS
    ${${my_list}}
  )

  string(REPLACE "-O4" "-Oz" ${my_list} "${${my_list}}" PARENT_SCOPE)

endfunction(foo)
```

......

```
foo(my_list)
message(
    STATUS
    ${${my_list}}
  )
```

I expect that the message from inside the foo function will print the list value, but instead it prints "my_list"
also, I expect that after foo function returns, the my_list will be changed ("-Oz" instead of "-O4", but its not being changed)

Comment: What is content of the `my_list` variable when you pass it to the function `foo`? Exactly this content is printed with the `message()` inside the `foo`. BTW, there is NO `PARENT_SCOPE` option for [string(REPLACE)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/string.html#replace) command. You need to separately replace the string, storing the result in the local variable, and set a variable for the outer scope with `set(... PARENT_SCOPE)`.